# Loop through a specific portion of a script until a specific requirement is fulfilled

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Is there any way for me to loop through a specific part of a script until a specific variable is set?

What I mean by this is, I have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if sudo
if [ $UID -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "You have to run this as sudo" 1>&2
        exit 1
fi

# Get the date for the check
read -p "Please input a date, format 'Jan 12': " chosendate

# Get the time for the check
read -p "Please input the time, format '13:55', leave blank for no time: " chosentime

# Get last results based on input
gotresults=$(last |grep "$chosendate $chosentime" |awk '{print $1" " $5" " $6" " $7" " $9}')

if [[ $(echo "$gotresults"|wc -l) -ne 1 ]]; then
        echo "There are multiple entries corresponding to your input"
        echo
        echo "$gotresults"
        echo
read -p "Please select which entry you desire by typing in the time: " chosentime
        echo "$gotresults" |grep $chosentime
else
        echo "$gotresults"
fi
```

I want to replace this with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if sudo
if [ $UID -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "You have to run this as sudo" 1>&2
        exit 1
fi

**FLAG1**
# Get the date for the check
read -p "Please input a date, format 'Jan 12': " chosendate

# Get the time for the check
read -p "Please input the time, format '13:55', leave blank for no time: " chosentime

# Get last results based on input
gotresults=$(last |grep "$chosendate $chosentime" |awk '{print $1" " $5" " $6" " $7" " $9}')

if [[ $(echo "$gotresults"|wc -l) -ne 1 ]]; then
        echo "There are multiple entries corresponding to your input"
        echo
        echo "$gotresults"
        echo
        echo "Please select a date/time that only returns one value"
        **GO TO FLAG1**

else
        echo "$gotresults"
fi
```

This way I could loop through that one part (reading the user input and then doing the operation) until based on the user input there's only one value returned.

I think this is possible with a "for" loop, but I would find it easier if such a thing would exist (I think this system was implemented in some kind of program I used to use).

The reason I would prefer the FLAG and GO TO FLAG system that I mentioned, is because I could go back to a flag whenever I want throughout the script, and I would have higher control over the flow of the script.
So I could have FLAG1 somewhere, and then GO TO FLAG1 in multiple parts of my script, not just one, which would be difficult to do with for loops.

Comment: I would use [functions](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) for such a task.

Comment: Yes I just thought of it as well :) but how come bash doesn't have this concept of GO TO? I'm told c++ has it

Comment: [Go to statement considered harmful](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf), a concept as valid nowadays as when the paper was written in 1968 :-)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that script ?

Answer (score 1):

With just the script from the question I probably would do something like (ignoring other potential improvements for now)

```
 have_results=0
 while [[ $have_results -eq 0 ]]; do
     read -p "Please input a date, format 'Jan 12': " chosendate
     read -p "Please input the time, format '13:55', leave blank for no time: " chosentime

     gotresults=$(last |grep "$chosendate $chosentime" |awk '{print $1" " $5" " $6" " $7" " $9}')

    if [[ $(echo "$gotresults"|wc -l) -ne 1 ]]; then
        echo "Please select a date/time that only returns one value"
    else
        have_results=1
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! But I'd specifically try to avoid for or while loops

Comment: @user317076 You can't have loops without loops :-) And your question asks for a loop.